# Drawing a letter from a model in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, drawing, interpolation

I'm a beginner in iOS developing.
I wanted to develop a SwiftUI app (for children) which detect the drawing of a letter (for example "A") of a user, from a model displayed (an image of "A"). If the user is drawing out of the model, a popup indicates to draw in the model.
I don't ask the code which doesn't help me to learn but the frameworks to use to detect the gestures of "hand" and if the model zone is quite filled.

Thanks a lot for your answer,
Regards. Armand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact i don't have a code yet, and just know that to draw, i have to use PencilKit. But i don't know which framework to use to control user gesture while drawing (ideally in proposed canvas).

Comment: Since you are talking about detecting I would say do some research on CoreML. There are a ton of tutorials out there about using it to detect handwriting and even Sign Language if you want to use the camera for writing in the air.

Comment: Thanks a lot. will search in these directions